# Empty register in vimscript

Tags: clipboard, vim

How do I empty a register if the user enters the name of the register?

p.e.
   `let r = inputdialog(toregister)`
   `let @r = ""`

(r = character received from inputdialog)

This doesn't work either:
   `let @{r} = ""`

Comment: Ok, please rephrase the question. `if register is created from inputdialog` is not clear by any stretch of imagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let r = inputdialog("which register do you want to empty?")
exe 'let @'.r.' = ""'
```

Don't forget to test `r` is one char long, and within *a-z* range (in order to avoid code injection)

Comment: @Luc, thank you, that works. Still don't understand why I can't use {} to create a variable on the fly, as with other variables.

Comment: @Remonn: registers are limited. You cannot create your own registers, the 26 lettered ones, plus the 10 digit-registers, plus some special registers (`/`, `"`, `_`, `-`, `:`, `.`,`%`,`#`,`*`,`+`,`~`,`=` which is the most special of all) are all the available registers. See `:help registers`. So, there is no register that you can create, delete, unlet, or whateverly manipulate outside of this list.

Comment: `{}` is nice, but it doesn't work everywhere. Sometimes we have to fall back to old vim scripting and use `:exe`

Comment: @Benoit, I noted that my macros in the digit-registers aren't permanent. These registers are emptied after a while. (Maybe they are used as system registers)

Comment: @Remonn, Digit-registers evolute every time you yank, or delete text with `c`, `d`, `y`, `C`, `D`, `Y`, `S`, and all other normal mode commands that I don't think of. Read `:help registers` one more time!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `:execute` and having to be aware of code injections I suggest you use `setreg` function:

```
call setreg(tolower(r), "")
```

`tolower()` is here because if user supplies `A` as a register name then an empty string will be appended to `a` register instead of emptying it.

`setreg()` will take only first byte of `r` and if it is valid register name then no errors will be thrown (`setreg("abc", "")` will empty register `a`).

Comment: ZyX's solution is much better than mine, when `setreg()` is available.